# Android: requestFileSystem in WebView causing crash

Tags: javascript, android, crash, android-webview, html5-filesystem

I'm developing an offline app where I have to save files in html5 fs-sandbox.
At desktop in Chrome everything works fine.

But my android device is crashing with `10-12 10:49:53.953: A/libc(9231): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1)` until I'm calling `window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 5*1024*1024, fsInit, errorHandler);`

Because `window.storageInfo`is not defined in my WebView I could not call `requestQuota` in first. But `window.requestFileSystem` is defined <strike>and I think the crash results from the missing granted quota</strike>. Even when using `window.TEMPORARY` and/or a lower size it causes the error.

---

**UPDATE:**
Bug reported: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38420