# Android: How to request quota in WebView

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, html5-filesystem

Relating to the Problem [Android: requestFileSystem in WebView causing crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12855822/android-requestfilesystem-in-webview-causing-crash) this questions rose up.

To request space and gain access you have to call `window.storageInfo.requestQuota()`. In Chrome that's no problem, but in android WebView the function is unknown.

In Chrome you have to use `window.webkitStorageInfo` -> is there a similar prefix for Android?